# Python 3.x Finding a string in a list imperfectly

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks like

```
stopCommands = {"quit": "I will quit now", "stop": "Goodbye!"}
```

and then I have code that looks through that, and if the variable is equal to one of those, it prints the value

```
userInput = input("Enter your command: ").casefold()
if userInput in stopCommands
    print(stopCommands[userInput])
```

This works, but what if a user misspells or if he enters `shut off` instead of `shut down`?

How can I make the searching account for these errors and pick the correct thing at least some of the time?

Comment: You will have to do some kind of fuzzy matching, which is too broad for an SO question.

Comment: 1. That's a list, not a dictionary. 2. If the user misspells a word then then comparison fails. You'd need to add some (complex) algorithm to check for similar words

Comment: You are expecting `stopCommands` as `dict` and  retrieving its value like `dict` but in actual you are have `list` object. You need to fetch value using `index` (which are `int` values)

Comment: The user will use [ctrl] + [C].if he wants to leave...

Comment: Sorry about the wrong naming.

Answer (score 1):

For misspelling, check out the fuzzywuzzy library.

To be more flexible in general, other than listing every possible command you can think of:

1. Remove all spaces from the user input first, so you don't have to list both `shut down` and `shutdown`. In fact just remove all characters other than letters, so for example adding a period at the end is fine.
2. Check if the input *contains* words like `off`, `quit`, or `exit`, instead of strict equality.